# Django not loading static from nginx in docker container

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I django server cannot load static files, however they are accessible directly through a URL.

I have a django server that is served by gunicorn inside a docker container.

My Django static sttings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")),
]

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../static"))
```

My Nginx conf:

```
http {
    sendfile on;
    

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://gunicorn:8000;
        }
        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /static/;
        }
    }
}
```

My nginx docker-compose configuration:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.6-alpine
    depends_on:
      - gunicorn
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - nginx_static:/static
```

When i start the django server with debug mode on, the files load at localhost:8000 where the gunicorn container is, but they are not avaliable at localhost:80 where my nginx container is.

When I start it with debug off, static files arent loaded at all.

When I try to access a static file through nginx, e.g. `localhost:80/static/my_static.css` the file loads

I think this may be an issue with my django settings as calling the static in a html template like: `{% static 'img/logo.png' %}` will load that image, however none of my other css files will load even though `{% load static %}` is on every template

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Because CSS files are not templates, they are themselves static assets, served directly by nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that nginx was serving my css as a text file not a css file. fix was to include MIME types `include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;`:

```
http {
    sendfile on;
    

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://gunicorn:8000;
        }
        location /static/ {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            autoindex on;
            alias /static/;
        }
    }
}
```